# How do I get slug of all active plugins programmatically?

Tags: plugins, slug

I want to check plugin version using following API

```
https://api.wordpress.org/stats/plugin/1.0/{slug}
```

For that how can I get Slug of All Active Plugins ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use option `active_plugins` to get all plugin init files. e.g.

```
$current = get_option( 'active_plugins', array() );
// print_r( $current );
```

Here, `htmlpress` is the plugin slug.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:

```
    <?php 

// Check if get_plugins() function exists. This is required on the front end of the
// site, since it is in a file that is normally only loaded in the admin.
if ( ! function_exists( 'get_plugins' ) ) {
    require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php';
}

$all_plugins = get_plugins();

print_r( $all_plugins);
```

Results:

```
  Array
    (
        [hello-dolly/hello.php] => Array
            (
                [Name] => Hello Dolly
                [PluginURI] => http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/hello-dolly/
                [Version] => 1.6
                [Description] => This is not just a plugin, it symbolizes the hope and enthusiasm of an entire generation summed up in two words sung most famously by Louis Armstrong: Hello, Dolly. When activated you will randomly see a lyric from <cite>Hello, Dolly</cite> in the upper right of your admin screen on every page.
                [Author] => Matt Mullenweg
                [AuthorURI] => http://ma.tt/
                [TextDomain] => 
                [DomainPath] => 
                [Network] => 
                [Title] => Hello Dolly
                [AuthorName] => Matt Mullenweg

    )
```

Reference: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_plugins

Answer (score 0):

If your are not on a multisite installation, you can have activated plugins with this code :

```
$active_plugins = get_option( 'active_plugins', array() );
```